# using web cam in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

im trying to create a chrome extension for my company's web app, but upon reading the docs i couldnt find any permission or chrome api that allows a chrome extension to access the webcam, all i could see were permissions to record screens. is there anyway a chrome extension can access a users webcam? or i would have to look for other means.
my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Intaclips",
  "description": "Intaclips chrome extension for intaviewer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons":{
    "19": "./icons/icon-19.png",
    "32": "./icons/icon-32.png",
    "48": "./icons/icon-48.png",
    "128": "./icons/icon-128.jpg"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["./background.js"]
  },
  "options_page": "./options.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "activeTab",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "cookies",
    "storage",
    "https://www.app.intaviewer.com/*",
    "https://www.google.com/*",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://static.opentok.com/v2/js/opentok.min.js; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Help in solving this issue will be well appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a third party library like "p5.js"